# Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Mageplaza\EmailAttachments\Mail\EmailMessageFactory does not exist

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.3

i am getting below error when i open vitalticks.in

```
exception(s):
Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Mageplaza\EmailAttachments\Mail\EmailMessageFactory does not exist

Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Mageplaza\EmailAttachments\Mail\EmailMessageFactory does not exist
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php:49]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:100]
#3 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70]
#4 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php:167]
#5 Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder->__construct() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder/Interceptor.php:14]
#6 Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder\Interceptor->__construct() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:116]
#7 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:108]
#8 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:150]
#9 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->get() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:79]
#10 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:150]
#11 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->get() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:79]
#12 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:150]
#13 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->get() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:79]
#14 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70]
#15 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/PluginList/PluginList.php:250]
#16 Magento\Framework\Interception\PluginList\PluginList->getPlugin() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:119]
#17 Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#18 Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php:26]
#19 Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:159]
#20 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:99]
#21 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#22 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#23 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php:94]
#24 Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#25 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php:73]
#26 Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#27 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#28 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:26]
#29 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:137]
#30 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:261]
#31 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [index.php:39]
</pre>
```

Answer (score -1):

1. chmod-R 777 var/ pub/ generated/
2. php bin/magento setup:upgrade
3. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
4. php bin/magento indexer:reindex
5. php bin/magento c:f